# Is there a simple javascript library that contains a lot of basic utility functions?

Tags: library, javascript, utility

I'm thinking something like lodash - but lodash doesn't have the functions I'm thinking of.

One's I'm thinking of are:

**round to increment places**

eg.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953384/javascript-round-up-to-the-next-multiple-of-5

**random int in range**

eg:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range

**deep copy (copy prototype as well**

eg.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474986/how-to-clone-a-javascript-es6-class-instance

I'm thinking about otherwise creating a library containing all the these functions that I use pretty frequently, but it seems a bit silly.

Comment: I was going to say "underscore.js" but then saw that lodash is based on underscore... Still, at least the second thing you want seems to exist in lodash ([random](https://lodash.com/docs/#random)), unless I misunderstand what exactly is being asked for.